# PHP 7.2 Cannot use string offset as an array in eval

Tags: php, eval, php-7.2

The code was working in php 7.0 . I am getting error after moved to 7.2 version .
I need help in understand this .
I have an $map  and $tempArray
print_r value of $locMap is given below

```
Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 1
                [LEVEL] => 1
                [NAME] => Operations1
                [CLASS] => ["e2"]["00"]

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 2
                [LEVEL] => 1
                [NAME] => POperations2
                [CLASS] => ["e2"]["01"]

            )

        [26] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 26
                [LEVEL] => 2
                [NAME] => Operations3
                [CLASS] => ["e2"]["01"]["e2"]["00"]

            )
    )
```

print_r value of $tempArray is as below

```
Array
    (
        [account] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1000
                        [name] => Homes
                        [level] => 
                        [rno] => 9
                    )

            )

    )
```

Looping this $map as below

```
foreach ($map $rec=>$det) {
     $dummyArray = array();
     $dummyArray['id'] = $det['ID'];
     $dummyArray['CLASS'] = $det['CLASS'];
     eval("\$tempArray['account'][0]".$det["CLASS"]." = \$dummyArray;");
}
```

> Error: Cannot use string offset as an array in  *************: eval()'d code:1

Inside eval function, "\$tempArray['account'][0]" is a string and is concatenating with the string again. 
Why do I get the error in this case?
Help me understand this and how do I fix this issue ?

Comment: Why do you even need eval here?

Comment: Not sure the use of eval here . But its a age old code. I understand eval is there to evaluate the string as php code

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem comes your concatenation of `"\$tempArray['account'][0]".$det["CLASS"]." = \$dummyArray;"`. If you output the string, you can see what is evaluated. Most probably, you forgot [] around $det["CLASS"]. In your case, the first part might be a string, not an array.

By the way, I am not sure to understand what you want to do but I am not sure you use the easiest way.

I do not understand why it worked with php7.0.

Comment: The output of the evaluated string is 
     
$tempArray['account'][0]["2"]["00"] = $dummyArray;

Comment: OK. Do you need eval to do that ?

Comment: I am not sure , What is the reason behind of adding eval.

Comment: Since they are forming a php code by concatenating the string , we need eval .

Comment: You could use something like $$tempArray['account'][0]".$det["CLASS"] = $dummyArray; I do not like that kind of things but I think it would do the job faster.